# How to track finger pinch zoom scale and rotation angle on screen using javascript on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-canvas, touch-event

I am using the pointer events to track the pinch zoom and rotation from the mobile device.
Using the events `roation` and `scale` property but not getting the values from the events.

Here is the code i am using.

```
myCan.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (e.targetTouches.length > 1) {
       if (typeof e.rotation == "number")
           degrees = 360 - e.rotation;

       if (typeof e.scale == "number")
            scale = e.scale;

     }
});
```

I am expecting the rotation angle from two pointers touching the screen and scaled value from pinch and zoom on the element.

Comment: can you try with 'touchmove' instead of 'touchstart' refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchmove_event

Comment: I have already tried not getting the result i wanted.

Comment: hi can you add your html and css to your quesiton too?